# An example of a commutative ring in which every primary ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

It is clear that every prime ideal in a commutative ring is primary. The converse is false; for example, in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ the ideal $(p^2)$ is an example of a primary ideal that is not prime (where $p$ is a prime number). So my question is when does the converse hold:

> 1) Is there any characterization of commutative rings in which every
>   primary ideal is prime?

One class of rings satisfying the above condition are absolutely flat rings. In fact, it is known that in every absolutely flat ring every primary ideal is maximal (see, for example, exercise 3 in page 55 of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah & Macdonald). Here is my second question, that is more specific:

> 2) What would be an example of an ring in which every primary ideal is
>   prime, but not every primary ideal is maximal?

An answer for question 1) would probably solve 2) easily.

Thanks!

Comment: The powers of maximal ideals are primary and therefore a necessary condition is $m=m^2$ for any maximal ideal.

Comment: Building on @YACP's comment: Then the Krull Intersection Theorem shows that if $R$ has this property, is Noetherian and either a domain or local, then it must be a field.  I think though that there are non-Noetherian domains which have the property: e.g. a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Well, a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies YACP's necessary condition at least.  Its only nonzero prime ideal is the maximal ideal, which does satisfy $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}^2$.  I don't see any non-prime primary ideals at the moment, but I'm not yet prepared to claim that there are none.  (If this works it answers 2), because the zero ideal is primary but not maximal in this ring.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The rings with the property that primary ideals are maximal are von Neumann regular; see [here](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=2024).

Comment: @YACP: Interesting (though inconclusive).  Thanks.

Comment: @YACP: Thanks for the reference on von Neumann regular rings! And the necessary condition $m=m^2$ you give is quite nice.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Thanks for the insightful comments! This will give me an opportunity to learn about valuation rings :-)

Comment: @Prism: If you want to know (only!) as much about valuation rings as I do, see $\S$ 17 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Dear Pete, thanks! It will be pleasure to read. Only if Georgia was close to where I live, I would come and attend your lectures in real time. :)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Bad news about valuation rings of rank one: it can be proved that their maximal ideal has other primary ideals than the maximal ideal itself, that is, it is *branched*.

Comment: @YACP: Thanks for following up on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Claim:** $A$ is a ring such that every primary ideal is prime if and
  only if $A$ is absolutely flat.

Let us say a ring is a PP(primary is prime) ring if every primary ideal is
prime.

Suppose $A$ is absolutely flat, then $A$ is PP. (exercise 3 in page 55 of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah & Macdonald)

We only need to show that if $A$ is PP then $A$ is absolutely flat.

Notice that every primary ideal of $S^{-1}A$ is of the form $S^{-1}\mathfrak{q}$
where $\mathfrak{q}$ is a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal such that
$\mathfrak{p}\cap S=\emptyset$. And if $J/I$ (here $J\supset I$) is a
primary ideal of $A/I$ then every zerodivisor in $A/J=(A/I)/(J/I)$ is
nilpotent, so $J$ is is primary ideal of $A$.

Now it is easy to show that,  if $A$ is PP, then $S^{-1}A$ and
$A/I$ is PP for a multiplicatively closed subset $S$ and an ideal
$I$ and $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$ for every maximal ideal
$\mathfrak{m}$.

Based on these properties we are able to prove that PP rings are absolutely
flat.

We first show every prime ideal in $A$ is maximal. Suppose not, there are
two distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{m}$ where
$\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal. Now $B=(A/\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is
a PP, local domain(but not a field) we also use $\mathfrak{m}$ to
denote the maximal ideal of $B$. Let $0\neq b\in \mathfrak{m}$,
suppose $\mathfrak{q}$ is a minimal prime containing $b$, then
$C=B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is a PP, local domain(not a field) and the only  maximal ideal of
$C$ is minimal over the ideal $(b)=bC$ so $(b)$ is primary and hence
maximal, $(bC)^2=bC$, thus $bC=0$. It is impossible. We have proved
that every prime ideal in $A$ is maximal.

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be any prime ideal in $A$, then $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$
is PP. If $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is not a field, pick any nonezero $x\in
\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}$, then $(x)$ is primary hence  equals
$\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}$, so $\mathfrak{m}A_m=0$,
contradiction.

Hence every prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$ is maximal and
$A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a field, so $A$ is absolutely flat. We are done.

Comment: Thanks very much! +1 Allow me some time to absorb this argument :)